# zipdir with nodejs compression files with parent folder

Tags: node.js

```
zipdir('/path/to/be/zipped', { saveTo: '~/myzip.zip' }, function (err, buffer) {
  // `buffer` is the buffer of the zipped file
  // And the buffer was saved to `~/myzip.zip`
});
```

I have try to compress folder with files but it has compressed file but when extract this file give me /* files only with out parent folder zipped/*, how can i do this process !?

Comment: can you elaborate more? I did not get what are you trying to reach? Are those files are missed after compression? Which `process` do you want to do?

Comment: i want after extract give my all files in folder "zipped" @Andy

Comment: so, basically, you want to unzip it, right?

Comment: I resolved by create folder inside zipped folder and give it name zipped too and compressed the parent one